# ASP.NET Logging onto web service using username and password the first time only

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, security

The first time I log onto my webservice I want to use FormsAuthentication e.g.

```
myService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "name";
myService.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```

but once a user has logged onto my web app I dont want to have to know about his password so I would like to be able to connect to the webservice as this user without knowing his password. Is this possible?

Comment: Are the users accessing the WCF services directly with a browser or is there a layer of aspx pages in between?

Comment: Where you ever able to solve this problem? I am stuck with the same issue as you.

Answer (score 0):

I would save the password on whatever front end is accessing the web service and then pass it behind the scenes whenever the user called the web service.

So essentially, design your web service take a password always, but have the front end cache the password so once the user enters the password, the front end doesn't ask again.

Be forewarned, there may be a security concern with keeping the password cached, as I believe that would be part of the session. I'm not familiar with how .net handles this, but you may want to look into [hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

Comment: Yes, I'm not able to store the password anywhere except hashed tec inside the database so this wouldn't work for me.

Comment: AJM, you might want to make the web service accept a pre-hashed password, and have the frontend hash the password before it caches it.

Comment: Or look into HTTPS for your front end.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this, but there are several issues to consider. Forms-based Authentication (FBA) normally uses a cookie to track authentication.

1. Security - Configure the web application
   and web service to use the same FBA database.
2. Domain - As long as the web service
   is on the same domain as the web
   application, the web service can use
   the same authentication cookie. If the
   client has cookies disabled, then this
   may not work.
3. Cookie expiration - You need to configure
   the duration of the authentication to an
   acceptable time limit (30 minutes, 1 hour,
   1 day, or more) in the web.config file. This
   will allow the user to access the web service
   within a proper time frame after he or she
   has logged in.

Answer (score 0):

you can enable sessions in your webservice.  There is a simple token that you add in at the begining of the service declaration.

```
<WebMethod(True)> Method Name
```